# The type or namespace name 'IConvertible' could not be found

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, iconvertible

I am trying to implement IConvertible for custom transform. I am using .NET portable and it seems that it is not available there. But the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Portable Class Library
>     Supported in: Portable Class Library

I am a bit worried by this which also appears :

> This API is not CLS-compliant.

Is this the reason why it might not be getting resolved?
As per the documentation, it should be a part of `System` namespace.
I am trying to implement the interface in a structure.

Something on the lines of :

```
public struct ABC: Blah<Demo>, IConvertible 
{}
```

I have a feeling I am am missing out on something really small.
More information: I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8.

Comment: "Supported in: Portable Class Library" means - "there is some combination of targets that you can select when building a Portable Class Library where this type will be available" - but it does **not** mean "For any combination of targets in a Portable Class Library, this type will be available". So, what targets do you have selected in your PCL?

Comment: Right now I have got .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8 selected in Properties->Library->Targeting

Comment: Yeah, it's not supported in Windows Store apps.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Kindly put that as an answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: "This API is not CLS-compliant." should not be significant. That has more to do with whether names are upper-lower-case significant or not, which can be a problem for VB.Net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Supported in: Portable Class Library" is merely the start of working out whether it's supported in *your* scenario. You also have to look at the further information about support to see whether your PCL targets are supported. You've said you're targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8. Let's compare the support information for `IConvertible` and, say `IComparable`:

[`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   **.NET for Windows Phone apps**
>   Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

And [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   **.NET for Windows Store apps**
>   Supported in: Windows 8
>   **.NET for Windows Phone apps**
>   Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

So, after we've established "it's supported in a PCL", you then need to look at the other sections and compare that to your set of targets. If any of your targets isn't *also* listed as supported, then you'll not be able to use that type in your current PCL (without removing the targets that aren't supported)

Comment: Just to add - it is still supported in .NET 4.6.1 and in .NET Core projects.

Comment: Can't seem to find `IConvertible` in PCL.

Comment: @Shimmy Same here.